# Sort nested python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to sort the keys in the first dictionaries in a nested dictionaries on the start value inside a the third dict.

I understood how to do it with 2 levels nested python dictiories and `lambda` functions, but I'm not getting the solution for my problem

I want the list of first level keys ordered eg. by start value:

```
your_list = {'KEY3': {'foo':{'start':1,'stop':2}},
            'KEY2': {'bar':{'start':3,'stop':4}},
            'KEY1': {'foobar':{'start':2,'stop':2}}}

KEY3 KEY1 KEY2
```

Comment: Dictionaries do not have an order to begin with… how exactly are you sorting them with 2 levels…?

Comment: what do you want as output?

Comment: What happens if the 2nd level has more than one key? Also, it is not clear what you are sorting by; your output order suggests the `start` values, but are `stop` values used in case of a tie?

Comment: You still have to pick an output for each 2nd level, even if that is a random key-value pair out of each: `lambda key: next(iter(yourlist[key].values()))['start']` would do just that.

Comment: i want the list of first level keys ordered eg. by start value

Comment: It's not that hard to tell what the question is asking.  I was posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to do it with lambdas but with a function it works

```
def func(key):
    for key2,value2 in your_list[key].iteritems():
        for key3, value3 in value2.iteritems():
             return value3

sorted(your_list,key=func)
```

this sort on the start values [1,3,2] 
output:

```
['KEY3', 'KEY2', 'KEY1']
```

Comment: `next(iter(your_list[key].values()))` gives a random value from the nested dictionary (Python 2 and 3).

Comment: since I can't post an answer, and yours is getting close to mine, may I edit in a small change for your approval, @J. Goedhart?

Comment: sure what do you want to change

Comment: I transformed the first dict into [(k, extract_third_level(v)) for k, v in data.iteritems()] with the helper function making it clear what you are sorting by. That gives a simpler problem that the OP has already solved. Irrelevant now that it's accepted. Although I think it still has a problem.